# No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I am struggling in understanding why this error is happening.  I am porting a tutorial over to the latest version of Spring, Hibernate, and WildFly.  I am running from the commandline building and testing the application using Maven.  I am getting the below error:

> Jul 10, 2015 2:18:03 PM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager prepareTestInstance
>   SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@523884b2] to prepare test instance [com.russ.home.test.dao.CompanyDaoTest@131774fe]
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.russ.home.test.dao.CompanyDaoTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests.setDataSource(javax.sql.DataSource); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

This is my **testing application context** file:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
             class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
             p:location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

       <bean id="tttDataSource"
             class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
             p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
             p:url="${jdbc.url}"
             p:username="${jdbc.username}"
             p:password="${jdbc.password}"
               />


       <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
             class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
             p:showSql="true"
             p:databasePlatform="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />

       <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
             class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
             p:persistenceUnitName="ttt-jpa"
             p:dataSource-ref="tttDataSource"
             p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaVendorAdapter"
             p:persistenceXmlLocation="classpath*:META-INF/test-persistence.xml"
               />

       <!-- Transaction manager for a single JPA EntityManagerFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
       <bean id="transactionManager"
             class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
             p:dataSource-ref="tttDataSource"
             p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

       <!-- checks for annotated configured beans -->
       <context:annotation-config/>
```

This is the **Abstract Test Class**

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration
        ({
                "classpath*: /testingContext.xml",


        })
public abstract class AbstractDaoForTesting extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());


    @Autowired(required = true)
    protected CompanyDao companyDao;
    @Autowired(required = true)
    protected ProjectDao projectDao;
    @Autowired(required = true)
    protected TaskDao taskDao;
    @Autowired(required = true)
    protected UserDao userDao;
    @Autowired(required = true)
    protected TaskLogDao taskLogDao;


}
```

This is the **CompanyDAOTest** Class.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class CompanyDaoTest extends AbstractDaoForTesting {

    public CompanyDaoTest(){}

    /**
     * Test case for the find(id) method of the CompanyDao implementation
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Test
    public void testFind() throws Exception {

        logger.debug("\nSTARTED testFind()\n");
        List<Company> allItems = companyDao.findAll();

        assertTrue(allItems.size() > 0);

        // get the first item in the list
        Company c1 = allItems.get(0);

        int id = c1.getId();

        Company c2 = companyDao.find(id);

        assertTrue(c1.equals(c2));
        logger.debug("\nFINISHED testFind()\n");
    }
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Russ

Comment: Can I see com.russ.home.test.dao.CompanyDaoTest?

Answer (score 2):

After comparing others application context files and re-reading Spring documentation, I learned that I was missing several things.  I started over and created this new application context and moved pass this error.

```
<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes for ex @Autowired -->
    <context:annotation-config/>


    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="tttDataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${jdbc.url}"
          p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}"
            />


    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
          p:showSql="true"
          p:databasePlatform="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />



    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          p:persistenceUnitName="ttt-jpa"
          p:dataSource-ref="tttDataSource"
          p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaVendorAdapter"
          p:persistenceXmlLocation="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml"
            />

    <!-- Transaction manager for JTA  -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
          p:dataSource-ref="tttDataSource"
          p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

    <!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />


    <!-- Scan for Repository/Service annotations -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.russ.home.dao"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.russ.home.service"/>
```